# Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, leaflet

I have to use leaflet-pixi-overlay library in my angular 7 project so
I've installed and imported the required libraries as cited in https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay:

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import {pixiOverlay} from 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
```

When I call the library function like:

```
147 - const a = pixiOverlay(
148 -       (utils) =>  {
149 -      // your drawing code here
150 - }, new PIXI.Container());
```

I get the following error:

```
zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at MapComponent.push../src/app/modules/map/components/map/map.component.ts.MapComponent.ngOnInit (map.component.ts:147)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18668)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19932)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19894)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20528)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20488)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (VisionClientComponent.html:17)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20480)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19876)
at callViewAction (core.js:20117)
```

Any clues? Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code around map.component.ts line 147?

Comment: `ngOnInit(): void {
    const a = pixiOverlay(
      (utils) =>  {
      // your drawing code here
    }, new PIXI.Container());

    // Permet de recentrer la map quand on slide sur la gauche
    if (this.onComponentResize) {
      this.onComponentResize.subscribe(() => {
        if (this.map) {
          this.map.invalidateSize();
        }
      });
    }
  }
`

Comment: Sorry but i can't format the code in the previous comment

Comment: Which one is line 147: `pixiOverlay` or `PIXI.Container()`?

Comment: pixiOverlay is the line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `leaflet-pixi-overlay` library does not export anything. It extends the `leaflet` library with the `pixiOverlay` method. So, just import the `leaflet-pixi-overlay` library and then, import `pixiOverlay` from the `leaflet` library.

```
import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay';
import { pixiOverlay } from 'leaflet';
```